# Как узнать что вышло новое видео на youtube-канале и как получить его url?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Пишу бота на pyTelegramBotAPI, нужно чтобы при выходе нового видео на ютубе кидал на канал что-то вроде

```
bot.send_video("channde_id", "адрес видео", "Комментарий от меня")
```

как это реализовать? Подозреваю, что через bs4, но как?

Comment: IFFFT что такое?

Comment: может имеется в виду IFTTT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подозреваю, что проще через rss - там структура изначально приспособлена для автоматического парсинга и есть гарантия, что изменение вёрстки ютуба не будут ломать вашего бота.

Каждый канал ютуба имеет rss-ленту, которую можно получить по адресу:
`https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=айдишник_нужного_канала`

А дальше всё просто - ваш бот с некоторой периодичностью получает xml по этой ссылке, парсит её, и смотрит - были ли изменения с момента последней проверки.

Xml с помощью питона парсится очень легко, погуглите, например,  `xml.etree.ElementTree`.

Comment: можно подписаться на [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications), вместо опроса. feedparser модуль позволяет `<feed/>` распознать.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы получить уведомления о новом видео на youtube-канале, можно подписаться на [push-уведомления](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications) (что может быть гораздо лучше, постоянного опроса youtube):

```
from aiohttp import ClientSession  # $ pip install aiohttp

async def subscribe_youtube_channel(channel_id, callback_url, *,
                                    lease_time=864000, subscribe=True):
    subscribe_url = 'https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/subscribe'
    topic_url = ('https://www.youtube.com/xml/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id='
                 + channel_id)
    data = {
        'hub.mode': 'subscribe' if subscribe else 'unsubscribe',
        'hub.callback': callback_url,
        'hub.lease_seconds': lease_time,
        'hub.topic': topic_url
    }
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(subscribe_url, data=data) as r:
            log('url: %s, channel_id: %s status: %s',
                subscribe_url, channel_id, r.status)
            return r.status
```

где

- `channel_id` это id YouTube-канала. К примеру, если ссылка на канал это https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw, то `channel_id == 'UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw'`
- `callback_url` это адрес, на который вы хотите чтобы приходили уведомления (на ваш сервер).

Я использовал [`aiohttp` модуль](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html) просто для примера — здесь подойдёт любой http-клиент.

Чтобы подписка сработала, необходимо ответить на GET http-запрос по `callback_url`, к примеру используя вот такой [http-cервер, на основе aiohttp модуля](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#server-tutorial):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from aiohttp import web

def hub_challenge(request):
    return web.Response(text=request.query['hub.challenge'])

app = web.Application()
resource = app.router.add_resource('/callback/{channel_id}')
resource.add_route('GET', hub_challenge)
resource.add_route('POST', feed_callback)  # см. ниже


if __name__ == "__main__":
    web.run_app(app)
```

в данном случае `callback_url` имеет вид `http://example.com/callback/<channel_id>`.

Push-уведомления c видео-ссылками приходят как POST http-запросы с [xml, содержащим rss-ленту](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications), которая распознаётся используя [feedparser модуль](http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/introduction.html#parsing-a-feed-from-a-remote-url):

```
import asyncio
import feedparser  # $ pip install feedparser

async def feed_callback(request):
    xml = await request.text()
    feed = feedparser.parse(xml)
    for e in feed.entries:
        text = (f'channel: {e.yt_channelid}\n'
                f'video_url: {e.link}\n'
                f'title: {e.title}')
        asyncio.ensure_future(send_telegram(text))
    return web.HTTPCreated()  # 201
```

Для каждого видео в rss-ленте, [бот посылает сообщение в telegram](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage):

```
import os

async def send_telegram(text):
    token = os.environ['TELEBOT_TOKEN']
    chat_id = os.environ['TELEBOT_CHAT_ID']
    api_url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage'
    data = dict(chat_id=chat_id, text=text)
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(api_url, data=data) as r:
            log('text: %s, status: %s', text, r.status)
```

код использует `TELEBOT_TOKEN`, `TELEBOT_CHAT_ID` переменные окружения. [Полный пример кода](https://gist.github.com/zed/a48da032ace0f4ff1c79cd80854bb8fd).