# Почему YouTube Data API v3 ругается на огромное кол-во запросов?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Есть некоторый список каналов, который я отслеживаю.

В понятие "отслеживаю" входит добавление новых видео канала. Делаю я это запросом:

> `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet,id&type=video&channelId=key&key=key&order=date&maxResults=50`

Запрос в задаче. Задача запускается каждые 20 минут с помощью CRON.

В сводке по квотам в ПУ Google API я вижу это (скриншот): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y024z.png

То есть каждый запуск задача делает более 6000 запросов, хотя внутри задачи четко прописан один URL и четко прописан один запрос. В ответ я получаю список видео и никаких более запросов к YouTube Data API v3 я не делаю.

В чем проблема? Откуда такое число запросов?

**ДОБАВЛЕНО**

Прошли сутки. Сбросились квоты.

Я выполнил задачу, в которой было ровно 10 запросов (для 10 каналов) по URL, который я привел выше. Сам "запрос" производился этим кодом:

```
Net::HTTP.get_response(URI(URI.encode(url)))
```

Дальше я просто парсил JSON и записывал данные в БД.

А теперь самое интересное. До запуска задачи было 0 запросов. После запуска их стало 7140. То есть задача, которая имеет 10 итераций и один запрос в каждой итерации сделала 7140 запросов к YouTube Data API v3.

Серьезно? Я не понимаю в чем дело и как с этим быть...

Comment: Может вашим ключом пользуется третья сторона?

Comment: @Visman именно в те же самые моменты? Нет. Ключу дня 3 от силы.

Comment: Добавьте логирование всех запросов к Google API из вашего скрипта, раз сторонние запросы исключаете. И смотрите действительное положение дел по логам.

Comment: @Visman У меня код в 2 строки, который затрагивает запрос. Первая - это URL, а вторая - это: `Net::HTTP.get_response(URI(URI.encode(url)))`. Что тут логировать? По этому URL в моем таске никак не может быть даже больше 100 запросов. В таске есть цикл из 10 каналов. Это цикл делает 10 запросов. Я проверил - это факт. Внутри таска происходит ровно 10 запросов. В день может быть примерно 72 запуска задачи, то есть примерно 720 запросов за весь день. А как видно из графика, запуск задачи равен более 6000 запросам. Это херня какая-то...

Comment: @Visman дополнил вопрос, если вам интересно.

Comment: вместо polling более эффективно может быть  push-уведомления использовать [Как узнать что вышло новое видео на youtube-канале и как получить его url?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/723729/23044)

Comment: уменьшил тоже запросы до минимума, все равно с каждым днем все менее и менее с моим ключем хватает, что самое интересное, в гугл аккаунте у меня привязана карта сбербанка, в https://console.developers.google.com ввожу ее, бесполезно, ошибку выдает, мол не правильно введены данные

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В YouTube Data API v3 запрос не равен квоте. Бесплатной учетной записи дан лимит в один миллион квот.

Если говорить простым языком, то каждый запрос имеет вес в виде квот. Вес вы определяете сами: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/

Если брать конкретно мой пример (URL из моего вопроса), то в конце URL вы можете увидеть параметр `maxResults`, у которого есть значение в виде числа 50. Если вы замените 50 на, например, 5, то получите более "легкий" запрос, что в итоге выльется вам в меньшее кол-во использованных квот.

Таким образом все запросы к YouTube Data API v3 нужно максимально оптимизировать.