# Как написать в канал с помощью telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Использую `pytelgrambotapi` , нужно отправить N сообщение в N канал. 
Подскажите, каким методом это можно сделать? в документации не нашел по этому поводу ничего :с

Comment: 1- получите [chat_id](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32423837/4279) 2- используйте sendMessage ([`send_telegram()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/724388/23044))

Comment: больше способов chat_id получить https://github.com/GabrielRF/telegram-id/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что вы не нашли в документации, как отправлять сообщения?

```
    import telebot

    you_token = 'XXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXX'

    bot = telebot.TeleBot(you_token)

    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def handler_text(message):
        bot.send_message(message_chat_id, 'hello world')    

    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
# message_chat_id - id канала куда нужно послать сообщение
```

Comment: Ну и бота в админы канала добавить не забыть

Comment: обязательно!!!!

Comment: благодарю! Я просто искал особые методы для отправки в канал, а как оказалось, это делается как обычное сообщение))

Comment: ваш код отвечает на сообщение. Чтобы послать сообщение в любое время,   chat_id необходим

Comment: спасибо, исправил

Comment: @Alban как не админ и не получится добавить бота в канал (когда я последний раз смотрел)

Comment: @jfs не понял о чем ты

Comment: смысл chat_id, чтобы вне handler можно сообщение послать (не в ответ на действия пользователя), к примеру [при получении push-оповещения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/724388/23044).

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler()
def worker(message):
    aswers = 'Имя: ' + name + '\n'
           + 'Номер: ' + str(nomer) + '\n'
           + 'Город: ' + country + '\n'
           + 'Предмет: ' + subject + '\n'
           + 'Класс: ' + str(clas) + '\n '
           + 'Формат обучения: ' + formats +'\n'
           + 'Обучение: ' + individ + '\n'
           + 'День записи: ' + day
    if message.text == 'Да':
        channel_id = -123456789  # Здесь укажите ID Вашего канала
        bot.send_message(channel_id, str(aswers))
        stik = open('goodbye.tgs', 'rb')
        bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, stik, reply_markup=pytoshka)
    elif message.text == 'Нет':
        bot.message_handler(message.from_user.id, 'Окей, давай попробуем еще раз!)')
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Как вас зовут?')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_name)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]