# Как получить уведомление о выходе нового видео на youtube?

Tags: python, flask, youtube

Подскажите пожалуйста как на python и flask получить уведомление о выходе нового видео на канале youtube? Подписываюсь при помощи PubSubHubbub, после чего проверяю прописку - она имеется. Но при выходе нового видео на канале не приходят уведомления на /callback/

```
    @app.route('/callback/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def index():
      if request.method == 'POST':
          soup = BeautifulSoup(str(flask.request.get_data()), 'lxml')
          try:
             feed = soup.find('feed')
          except:
             return ''
          try:
             videoid = feed.find('yt:videoid').text
             print videoid
          except:
             return ''
      else:
           hub_challenge = str(request.args.get('hub.challenge'))
           return hub_challenge
```

Comment: [вот бот](https://gist.github.com/zed/a48da032ace0f4ff1c79cd80854bb8fd), который посылает в telegram сообщение, когда новое видео выходит на подписанных youtube-каналах. Связанный вопрос [Как узнать что вышло новое видео на youtube-канале и как получить его url?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/723729/23044)