# Программно узнать вживую о забитом голе на чемпионате мира по футболу

Tags: http, api, любой-язык, live

Слово api или developer не видать на https://www.fifa.com/worldcup/

Подсматривая сетевые запросы браузера можно найти ссылку, которая обновления получает как json:

https://api.fifa.com/api/v1/live/football/recent/17/254645?language=ru-RU

В принципе можно с помощью периодического опроса (polling) недавнюю информацию получить отсюда.

В комментариях к похожему вопросу [UEFA/FIFA scores API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13370914/4279), можно найти ссылку на информацию обо всех матчах сразу:

https://api.fifa.com/api/v1/calendar/matches?idseason=254645&idcompetition=17&count=100

Эту ссылку также можно подсмотреть в инструментах разработчика в сетевых запросах браузера, находясь на fifa.com

Поисковики ещё подсказывают https://worldcup.sfg.io — сайт, который как json похожую информацию возвращает соскребая её с сайта fifa. Есть и другие сайты.

Идеально хотелось бы найти API в открытом доступе, которое бы позволило подписаться на интересующие меня события, без необходимости постоянного опроса, чтобы свежую информацию получить. 
Пример такого API это сайт https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/, который позволяет подписаться на push-уведомления. См. [Как узнать что вышло новое видео на youtube-канале и как получить его url?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/723729/23044)

Comment: Не совсем понятно, для чего специально под этот вопрос созданы два тэга, которые к тематике сайта вообще не относятся.

Comment: @Эникейщик а вы подумайте зачем вообще метки существует и всё станет ясно. Если и подумав ничего в голову не придёт, спросите на Мете (спросив себя как ваше сообщение улучшает сайт, кому от этого лучше будет).

Comment: Как вообще соотносятся `fifa` и `live` с программированием? Ладно `live`, но `fifa` то тут причем? Не стоит все таки загрязнять ненужными метками сайт?
P.S. Только увидел дату вопроса. Все равно, стоило ли их создавать? По ним до сих пор 1 вопрос.

Comment: @AntonSorokin прочитайте мой предыдущий комментарий

Answer (score 7, accepted):

API с push-уведомлениями не нашёл. В качестве компромисса, написал скрипт, который спит до начала матча, а затем каждые полминуты делает запрос по [live ccылке, приведённой выше](https://api.fifa.com/api/v1/live/football/recent/17/254645?language=ru-RU) и сравнивает полученную информацию с уже сохранённой, чтобы узнать начался ли новый матч, забит ли новый гол.

Вот [код утилиты на Питоне, отсылающей телеграмму вначале матча/при забитии гола](https://gist.github.com/zed/d41457c752e2de867194fbcfe021c446).